# Can In-App-Purchase allow users to purchase an audio file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am trying to making a Music App Integrated with In-App Purchase where User can buy audio File?

Is In-App-Purchase Allow user to buy Audio File ????

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *allowed*, yes. However, there's no specific API for the selling of audio files, just an API that can be used to sell whatever content you like (with usual apple caveats). You'll need to have an apple developer account set up to sell paid apps to be able to build and test apps with in-app purchase.  Read through the docs at `https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/inapppurchase/`

.. it's something that'll take some time to get right, and much too complicated to explain in full here.